# ZF2 form validating value from select even when invalid values sent

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form2, zend-form-select

I have a form in my ZF2 application with a select element. In ZF1, it would automatically add a validator to check that the user wasn't trying to post invalid values to it.

So just for kicks and giggles, I decided to see what would happen if I used Firebug to alter the value of one of the options and then submit it. Result: it passed with flying colours. Needless to say, this is not good.

Here's the relevant code for the select option:

```
$this->add(array (
    'name' => 'role',
    'type' => 'Select',
    'attributes' => array (
        'id' => 'role'
    ),
    'options' => array (
        'label' => 'Role:',
        'value_options' => $roleOptions,
        'column-size' => 'sm-6',
        'label_attributes' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2'),
    )
));
```

(Note: $roleOptions is passed as a parameter into the form)

Here's the relevant part of the validator code:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array (
    'name' => 'role',
    'filters' => array(),
    'validators' => array(
        $notEmpty
    ),
)));
```

(Obviously, $notEmpty is an instance of the NotEmpty validator)

What's going on here? Does ZF2 no longer add a validator to ensure that the value it receives is one that was originally part of the list of options? Do I have to manually add a validator to select options now?

EDIT: I checked the documentation, and it says that the select element automatically adds an in array validator. It should be working, but it's not. I even tried changing the value on the server side, with the same results--the validator is not picking up the invalid value.

And yes, I am checking if the form is valid.

EDIT #2: For clarity, [here's the code for the form in its entirety](http://pastie.org/8952312)

Comment: One other thing: It seems as if the act of setting an input filter on the role element removes the built-in InArray validator. Unfortunately, removing it would make a mess as well--for the $form->bind() method to work properly, each element has to have an input filter set. So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this issue by setting the value of the select options to numbers:

In the form constructor:

```
// Gender field
$this->add
(
    array
    (
        'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name'       => 'gender',
        'attributes' => array
                        (
                            'id'     => 'GenderField',
                            'class'  => 'form-control',
                        ),
        'options'    => array
                        (
                            'label'         => 'Gender',
                            'empty_option'  => 'Please choose...',
                            'value_options' => array
                                               (
                                                   '1' => 'Female',
                                                   '2' => 'Male',
                                                   '3' => 'Other',
                                               ),
                        )
    )
);
```

and then in my InputFilter I added the Between validator to my NotEmpty validator like so:

```
'validators' => array
                (
                    array(...NotEmpty Validator...),
                    array
                    (
                        'name'    => 'Between',
                        'options' => array
                                     (
                                         'min'      => 1,
                                         'max'      => 3,
                                         'messages' => array
                                                       (...)
                                     ),
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                    ),
                 )
```

I also here its good practice to actually have an empty option because of the whole 0|NULL|'' issue:

```
'empty_option'  => 'Please choose...',
```

There is also an [InArray Validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#inarray) which is just as useful for non consecutive units...like ids:

```
$validator = new Zend\Validator\InArray(array('haystack' => array('value1',     'value2',...'valueN')));
if ($validator->isValid('value')) {
// value found
} else {
// no value found
}
```

Comment: That's all fair and good, but according to the documentation, the Zend\Form\Element\Select class automatically adds an InArray validator.